# Selecting rows that share a common value in one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table is as below:

[image]

From it I can see that some suppliers used the same ip address (which can be written in different ways). How do I write a sql query which can get me those suppliers who used the same ip address, given that

```
84.20.93.11- 84.20.93.11,  84.20.93.11
84.20.93.11- 84.20.93.11
84.20.93.11
```

are the same addresses ?

UPD: 
As a result, I want to get

[image]

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store ip address ranges as strings -- it is just painful, painful to have to parse that information in SQL.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: It's time to think about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Unfortunately have to work with what I have.

Comment: @kulan then blame the one who designed this

Comment: @kulan: or even better: make the person responsible for such a design write the query ;)

Comment: Just to get this right: some IP addresses are separated with a `-` and some are separated with a `,`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yep, all possible formats are in the screenshots.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the desired SQL query result, based on the sample data you provided in your question. Also, can either column `supplier_id` or `ip` contain null values?

Comment: @Abra I edited the question. And yes, they can contain null values.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert that "list" into an array and use that to look for other rows that have the same IP addresses.

Something along the lines:

```
select *
from the_table t1
where exists (select *
              from the_table t2
              where regexp_split_to_array(t1.ip, '\s*[^0-9.]\s*')
                    && regexp_split_to_array(t2.ip, '\s*[^0-9.]\s*')
                and t1.supplier_id <> t2.supplier_id)
```

The expression `regexp_split_to_array(t1.ip, '\s*[^0-9.]\s*')` converts the "list" of IP addresses into an array and splits on anything that is not an "IP address". So `regexp_split_to_array('84.20.93.11- 84.20.93.11,  84.20.93.11', '\s*[^0-9-, ]\s*')` returns the following array `{84.20.93.11,84.20.93.11,84.20.93.11}`

The `&&` then checks if the arrays of two suppliers overlap, i.e. if they have at least one IP address in common.

Comment: Please can you look at my update? All I want is to get distinct supplier_id

Comment: The use  `select distinct supplier_id ...`

Answer (score 0):

From the data you posted and according to the stated requirement and desired result in your question, a self-join will suffice.

I could not find the table name in your question, so I used SUPPLIERS as the table name.

```sql
select distinct s1.supplier_id
  from suppliers s1
  join suppliers s2
    on s1.ip = s2.ip
   and s1.ctid <> s2.ctid
```

Note that `ctid` is a unique ID for a row in a table that PostgreSQL generates. That criteria ensures that the query will not compare the same row in table S1 with the same row in table S2.